# Signed char to byte

Tags: java, c, type-conversion

I have a binary file written in C containing a signed char data type equal to the number 1.
I read in the single byte into a byte data type using MappedByteBuffer.
However, when I print it out I get 49. What am I doing wrong?

C:

```
char * buffer = malloc(100);
signed char c;
int temp;
printf("Coordinate System?\n");
scanf("%s",&buffer[0]);
sscanf(&buffer[0],"%d",&temp);
c = temp+'0';
fwrite(&c,1,1,fd);
```

Java:

```
byte b;
b = file.read();
System.out.println(b) ===> prints the number 49.
```

I know it is some kind of bit order or something but I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: How did you construct `file` in Java?

Comment: It can't be a concidence that '1' is ASCII 49.

Comment: I realize that. I am wondering how I can interpret it in another way.

Comment: @Fra: Try `signed char c = '1';`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't in C do `signed char c = '1';` or did you get `1` from somewhere else than you say? NB the `signed` is not necessary, `char` in C is signed.

Comment: @WeatherVane  _char in C is signed._ This is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Weather Vane: I parse it from the command prompt like above

Comment: Thank you, so its character '1' not numeric 1. You weren't doing what you originally posted.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes some implementations of C.

Comment: @WeatherVane  the standard say may be in either or mixed.

Comment: How would I handle the sscanf then? Something like: sscanf(&buffer[0],"%i",&c);

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with:

```
sscanf(&buffer[0],"%c",&c);
```

it says to scan the incoming character as an ascii value. so you can type 'a', '-', or '1' and the ascii value will be scanned.

you would need to scan `%d` instead to get an actual integer. you would scan into an int variable instead of a char, then do a 0-255 range check to determine if it's viable to store in a single byte.

Comment: I can't get it working on the Java side of things. Above is how I try and deal with it in C when writing the file.

Comment: Why are you adding '0' - what exactly do you want to do in this program? if you want to write an integer, you should not be converting it to ascii. if you want to write a character, then my answer is incorrect, and you simply need to convert from the byte to a char in Java.

Comment: I just want to store an integer read from the console as a one byte char for file size compression. So when I read it later I can read it as its integer representation not it's ASCII correlation.

Comment: If you don't want ascii, don't do `c = temp+'0'`, just do `c = temp`